# Highly customizable/templatable CCK for Joomla 3.x

Tags: joomla, content-management-system

I'm working on Event websites with Joomla, and the issue is that these websites require that their content be updated quite frequently. There are different types of content, such as Speaker, Partner Companies and a complex Agenda.

I'm looking for a CCK or other extension that will allow me to make custom data types - one each for Speakers, Partners, etc.

For example, the Speakers content type would contain -

- Their name
- Their company designation
- Their photograph
- Their Bio

I also need this to be very flexible in its templating, as some things need to be displayed in modals or otherwise.

Thus far, I have found Form2Content to be very helpful, I have also tried K2 and SEBLOD.

I'm wondering if there is a solution better than Form2Content to solve this issue - any help is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try use K2 and extrafields or write own K2 plugin for add some additional specific content type. With template hierarchy create own child k2 template in `templates/your_template/html/com_k2/your_new_tmpl/` where could be modals or otherwise.